towards our teens or in our teens
I was reading a text with missing prepositions with my students and one of them asked if we can use towards our teens instead of in our teens.  I told them we cannot, as "towards" requires some kind of movement or change, but I'm not completely sure. Can someone help?
Here is part of the text:

As babies and small children, we are mostly influenced by our parents and the people around us. When we come into contact with people from outside the family unit, we need to make sense of them……. Later, in our teens, we're typically influenced more by our friends and then by family members .At the same time the words and actions of public figures play an important part in our journey towards finding ourselves..........


Your intuition isn’t bad. Replacing in by towards in the passage you quote does make the sentence less idiomatic (indeed, Google n-gram finds no occurrences). But it is still acceptable English. Of course, making the replacement does change the sentence’s meaning: in our teens means during the period when we are between 13 and 19 years old, whereas towards our teens would be interpreted to mean as we approach age 13.
Merriam-Webster gives one sense of towards as "not long before" and includes as an example the phrase toward the end of the afternoon.

Can you find a dictionary definition of towards meaning [when] approaching? It's difficult to find an example of towards old age not preceded by a verb (hurtling, racing, stumbling...) or 'attitude/s.

@EdwinAshworth, done.

@PaulTanenbaum Thanks a lot! It really made things clear for me.

Since sense can be made of the preposition towards in that context, it isn't totally out of the question.   But the usual ways  of expressing that idea would be one of the following:

... as "tweens"  i.e. middle-schoolers in the US
... as pre-teens
... approaching our teens


Thank you for your answer!

But note, middle-schoolers don't refer to themselves as "tweens".  That's a convenient term used by  book publishers and clothing brands and child psychologists and magazines for parents of such children.
